# How can I format several Strings to get equal spacing when some of the Strings have different lengths

Tags: java, android, printf, string-formatting, formatter

I have tried using `String.format("%-10s %s %20s",stringPlaceNumber, userName, scoreNumberAsString);`
I get the following output
[High Scores Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLrAo.png).

How can I pad with the correct number of blank spaces or invisible characters to make it look properly spaced?

**Other info:** 
 -  This is on an Android so trying this in a terminal isn't that useful here. The font has a variable width (i.e. spaces can be smaller than the characters)

- The user's name comes from an Android EditText that gets entered into a SQLite database and an `BaseAdapter` puts the top 10 scores into the `ListView`.
- A user can enter a name for the score at the end of the game that is a maximum of *20* characters.
- This is the rest of the code

`listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return scores.size();
                }

```
            @Override
            public ScoreManager.Score getItem(int position) {
                return scores.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ScoreManager.Score score = getItem(position);

                TextView view = new TextView(ScoresActivity.this);

                view.setText(String.format("%-10s %s %20s", getPlaceNumber(position+1),score.name.trim(), formatScore(score.score).trim()));
                view.setTextSize(5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
                return view;
            }
        });
```

Comment: > blank spaces or invisible characters to make it look properly spaced. 
1. You mean in Listview, so why not use align the list view item instead?
2. About your format string, i tested and it ouputs string correctly.

Comment: From your image it just looks like you need a two-cell table; why only 1? This looks like a XY problem, `String.format()` will not help you here, especially since you are using a variable width font

Comment: I ended up slightly cheating. For now I am going to use a fixed width font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
String.format("%-10s %s %20s",stringPlaceNumber, userName.trim(), scoreNumberAsString.trim());
```

Comment: Well, it is worth checking the trim() function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use String's `.trim()` method.